# Двоичный поиск

Tags: алгоритм

скажите правильно ли я понял что в программе написанной на паскале ошибка в самом алгоритме, а в программе на C ошибки нет? Вот примеры реализации Binary Search.

```
function BinarySearch(var A:Array of integer;d:integer):integer;

var iStart,iEnd,iMid:integer;

begin
if Length(A)>0 then
 begin
 iStart:=0;
 iEnd:=high(A);
 while iEnd-iStart>1 do

   begin

     iMid:=(iStart+iEnd) div 2;

     if d>=A[iMid] then iStart:=iMid else iEnd:=iMid;

   end;

 if d=A[iEnd] then result:=iEnd else

   if d=A[iStart] then result:=iStart else Result=-1;

 end else Result=-1;

end;

public int runk(int key,int[] a){

  int lo=0;

  int hi=a.length-1;

   while (lo<=hi){

     int mid=lo+(hi-lo)/2;

     if(key>a[mid]){hi=mid-1;}

     else if(key<a[mid]){lo=mid+1;}

     else return a[mid];
    }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: @VashTheStempede, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: там 2 функции написаны одна на языке P{ascal, другая на языке C

Comment: и тут дело в вычислении среднего индекса mid=lo+(hi-lo)/2 - это правильно считает, а тут iMid=(iStart+iMid) div 2 не правильно

Comment: А это ничего что в этих строках на C и паскале написан разный код?

Comment: В функции на *Pascal* при вычислении `iMid` происходит переполнение. Сначала выполняется сложение двух индексов, а потом деление на 2. И при сложении результат выходит за максимально допустимое значение. Эту формулу следует заменить аналогом из функции на *C*.  (Аналогичный баг существовал в Java около 10-ти лет: http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)

Comment: хватит меня троллить - свою ошибку понял